# Need to provide margin left dynamically on root node text in d3 hierarchy chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchical-data

I'm utilizing the D3 collapsible tree feature and examining this particular code - [Collapsible tree](https://observablehq.com/@d3/collapsible-tree)

However, I've encountered an issue. The length of the texts I'm working with can differ based on the data. Whenever I modify the text length, the chart begins extending beyond its designated area. My familiarity with D3 is limited, and I've attempted to address this by experimenting with the code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-gwen-93t66m?file=/src/HierarchyTree.js).

Here's the code that has been taken from the above d3 website -

```
const PlotChart = () => {
// Specify the charts’ dimensions. The height is variable, depending on the layout.
const width = 928;
const marginTop = 10;
const marginRight = 10;
const marginBottom = 10;
const marginLeft = 40;

// Rows are separated by dx pixels, columns by dy pixels. These names can be counter-intuitive
// (dx is a height, and dy a width). This because the tree must be viewed with the root at the
// “bottom”, in the data domain. The width of a column is based on the tree’s height.
const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
const dx = 10;
const dy = (width - marginRight - marginLeft) / (1 + root.height);

// Define the tree layout and the shape for links.
const tree = d3.tree().nodeSize([dx, dy]);
const diagonal = d3
  .linkHorizontal()
  .x((d) => d.y)
  .y((d) => d.x);

// Create the SVG container, a layer for the links and a layer for the nodes.
const svg = d3
  .create("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", dx)
  .attr("viewBox", [-marginLeft, -marginTop, width, dx])
  .attr(
    "style",
    "max-width: 100%; height: auto; font: 10px sans-serif; user-select: none;"
  );

const gLink = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#555")
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.4)
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);

const gNode = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .attr("pointer-events", "all");

function update(event, source) {
  const duration = event?.altKey ? 2500 : 250; // hold the alt key to slow down the transition
  const nodes = root.descendants().reverse();
  const links = root.links();

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  tree(root);

  let left = root;
  let right = root;
  root.eachBefore((node) => {
    if (node.x < left.x) left = node;
    if (node.x > right.x) right = node;
  });

  const height = right.x - left.x + marginTop + marginBottom;

  const transition = svg
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", [-marginLeft*2, left.x - marginTop, width, height])
    .tween(
      "resize",
      window.ResizeObserver ? null : () => () => svg.dispatch("toggle")
    );

  // Update the nodes…
  const node = gNode.selectAll("g").data(nodes, (d) => d.id);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  const nodeEnter = node
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${source.y0},${source.x0})`)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
    .on("click", (event, d) => {
      d.children = d.children ? null : d._children;
      update(event, d);
    });

  nodeEnter
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .attr("fill", (d) => (d._children ? "#555" : "#999"))
    .attr("stroke-width", 10);

  nodeEnter
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", "0.31em")
    .attr("x", (d) => (d._children ? -6 : 6))
    .attr("text-anchor", (d) => (d._children ? "end" : "start"))
    .text((d) => d.data.name)
    .clone(true)
    .lower()
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 3)
    .attr("stroke", "white");

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  const nodeUpdate = node
    .merge(nodeEnter)
    .transition(transition)
    .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  const nodeExit = node
    .exit()
    .transition(transition)
    .remove()
    .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${source.y},${source.x})`)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0);

  // Update the links…
  const link = gLink.selectAll("path").data(links, (d) => d.target.id);

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  const linkEnter = link
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", (d) => {
      const o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
      return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.merge(linkEnter).transition(transition).attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link
    .exit()
    .transition(transition)
    .remove()
    .attr("d", (d) => {
      const o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
      return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
    });

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  root.eachBefore((d) => {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Do the first update to the initial configuration of the tree — where a number of nodes
// are open (arbitrarily selected as the root, plus nodes with 7 letters).
root.x0 = dy / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
root.descendants().forEach((d, i) => {
  d.id = i;
  d._children = d.children;
  if (d.depth && d.data.name.length !== 7) d.children = null;
});

update(null, root);
if (document.getElementById("app") !== null) {
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = "";
}
```

In the provided demonstration, there's an issue with the accurate display of the root node (flare | some random text - this is the text of the root node, but only a certain part of it is visible). The problem is resolved when a specific value is assigned to the left margin. I tried varying the marginLeft by multiplying by 2. However, the challenge remains, as I mentioned before, that the text length can differ in various situations. Therefore, it seems necessary to devise a method to dynamically establish the appropriate margin left based on these varying text lengths.

Furthermore, the text of intermediary nodes isn't being presented correctly either. Is there a potential solution to address these problems? Could the node length be adjusted so that lengthy texts remain visible within a consistent node size? Moreover, how can we guarantee that the root node consistently initiates from a specific point?

I attempted to find a solution by searching for answers, but unfortunately, none of the questions posted on Stack Overflow appear to provide a suitable response to this issue.

Comment: @musically_ut can you please help me out here?